# colorbar is distorting another subplot within the same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, colorbar

In the following code, a variable `mat_store` is displayed in the central axis, and then bar graphs of the collapsed (across each axis of the matrix) are shown on the top and side of the matrix.  I would also like to display the colorbar of the matrix at the bottom of the figure.

```py
        num_bins = mat_store.shape[0]
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16))
        gs = fig.add_gridspec(3, 2,  width_ratios=(7, 2), height_ratios=(2, 7, 0.5),
                        left=0.1, right=0.9, bottom=0.1, top=0.9,
                        wspace=0.05, hspace=0.15)

        ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
        ax_histx = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0], sharex=ax)
        ax_histy = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1], sharey=ax)
        ax_histx.tick_params(axis="x", labelbottom=False)
        ax_histy.tick_params(axis="y", labelleft=False)
        
        abs_serial = jnp.abs(mat_store)
        cur_trial_dependence = jnp.sum(abs_serial,axis=0)
        pre_trial_dependence = jnp.sum(abs_serial,axis=1)
        ax_histx.bar(np.arange(num_bins)-0.5, cur_trial_dependence, align="edge",color='k',linewidth=0,width = 1)
        ax_histy.barh(np.arange(num_bins)-0.5, pre_trial_dependence, height = 1, align="edge",color='k',linewidth=0,alpha=0.25)
        ax_histy.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
        ax_histx.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
        ax_histx.tick_params(
            which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
            bottom=False,      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
            top=False,         # ticks along the top edge are off
            labelbottom=False) # labels along the bottom edge are off
        ax_histy.tick_params(
            which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
            left=False,
            right=False,
            labelbottom=False) # labels along the bottom edge are off
        max_value = jnp.max(abs_serial)
        hist = ax.imshow(mat_store,origin="lower",cmap="seismic",vmin=-max_value,vmax=max_value)
        ax.set_ylabel(r"$S_{n-1}$")
        ax.set_xlabel(r"$S_{n}$")
        ax.set_title(r"$\langle \{S_{n-1},S_{n}\} \rangle - \langle S_{n} \rangle$")
        
        ax.set_yticks([0,num_bins-1])
        ax.set_yticklabels([r"$-\pi$",r"$\pi$"])
        ax.set_xticks([0,num_bins-1])
        ax.set_xticklabels([r"$-\pi$",r"$\pi$"])
        ax.plot([0,num_bins-1],[0,num_bins-1],color="white",ls="--",lw=2)
        ax.axvline((num_bins-1)/2,color="white",ls="--",lw=2)
        ax.axhline((num_bins-1)/2,color="white",ls="--",lw=2)
        col_ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, 0])
        fig.colorbar(hist,cax = col_ax,orientation="horizontal")
```

Which produces this image
[image]

As you can see, there are a couple of issues.

1. I would like to move the colorbar down, so it doesn't occlude the axis label, without also moving the top bar-plot up, so simply modifying the `hspace` parameter in `add_gridspec` isn't appropriate here.  Moving the axis labels (vertical too, for consistency) would also work, but I don't know how to do that either.
2. The bigger issue, on which I am mystified, is why adding the axtra axs in the gridspec makes the central axs shrink?  If I don't have that third row the matrix aligns perfectly with the bar plot in the top row.  Why does adding this third row change the width of the central axs?  And why does it not modify the top row?  How can I fix this such that edges of all the subplots are well aligned?

**EDIT**

Making the axis locateable does part of the trick.  The edited code is below

```
num_bins = mat_store.shape[0]
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16))
        gs = fig.add_gridspec(3, 2,  width_ratios=(7, 2), height_ratios=(2, 7, 0.5),
                        left=0.1, right=0.9, bottom=0.1, top=0.9,
                        wspace=0.05, hspace=0.15)

        ...
        
        divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
        cax = divider.new_vertical(size="5%", pad=0.7, pack_start=True)
        fig.add_axes(cax)
        fig.colorbar(hist,cax = cax,orientation="horizontal")
```

[image]
But as you can see, the main axs is still shrunk, though at least the colorbar is now in line with it.  Also, the right hand axes spans the whole two subplots, rather than just the central matrix.  I've tried using a `gridspec(2,2,...)` but this had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `pad` argument as in `fig.colorbar(hist,cax = col_ax,orientation="horizontal", pad=0.2)`. This modifies the position of the colorbar.

Comment: this helps to reveal the axis label, but not with the other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!  Setting the `figsize=(16,16)` was squasing the figure down, meaning the central matrix, in order to remain a square, was becoming smaller.  Changing it to `figsize=(16,17.55)` saved me.  To move around the axis titles I'm using the `labelpad` argument.